# Saving $ra in the stack (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

Why do I need to do

```
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, 0($sp)
```

in order to store the $ra in the stack, instead of just doing

```
sw $ra, -4($sp)
```

?

Comment: Because in the second example you haven't updated the stack pointer.

Comment: And is it important to do that? I mean, how does it make a difference? I still can access the $ra by doing lw $ra, -4(sp), right?

Comment: The whole point of a stack is that you can *push* things onto it and *pop* them off again later. If you don't adjust the stack pointer then the next push would overwrite your existing data - this is fine *iff* you are absolutely certain that there are going to be no further stack operations in the function, but it's not a very robust approach, for the sake of one instruction, and it will likely come back to bite you later.